# Output First of Month Following 60 Days From a Stored Date in an Access qry

Tags: ms-access

I have a date field in access where I have to calculate the first of the month following 60 days from that date. For example my date is 12/12/2017. I need to output 3/1/2018, First of the month following 60 days from 12/12/2017. I know how to use the DateAdd function to get my 60 days, but am confused as to how to output the first of the month following those 60 days.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. One way using `DATEADD()`:

```
SELECT DATEADD("d", -"d"(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD("d", 60, '2017/12/12')))+1,
        DATEADD("m", 1, DATEADD("d", 60, '2017/12/12')))
```

If you have Access 2013+ you can use `EOMONTH()`

```
SELECT DATEADD("d", 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD("d", 60, '2017/12/12')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
DateThreeFirst: DateAdd("m", 3, DateSerial(Year([YourDateField]), Month([YourDateField]), 1))
```

To first deduct one day:

```
DateThreeFirst: DateAdd("m", 3, DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("d", -1, [YourDateField])), Month(DateAdd("d", -1, [YourDateField])), 1))
```

To use days' count and not months:

```
DateThreeFirst: DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("d", 60, [YourDateField])), Month(DateAdd("d", 60, [YourDateField])) + 1, 1)
```

Comment: I used DateAdd("m",3,DateSerial(Year([Hire Date]),Month([Hire Date]),1)) and it seems to be working for most dates with the exception of 7/01/1998. Access is calculating it as 10/1/1998, but it should be 9/1/1998. 60 days from 7/1/1998 is 8/29/1998. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems like you have first to deduct one day. See edited answer.

Comment: That fixed for the 7/1/1998 date but as soon as I go out to 7/2/1998 Access is outputting 10/1/1998 and not 9/1/1998. This seems to be happening for months where there are two of them in a row with 31 days.

Comment: Yes. Try the modified method in the answer.